where the creation point of the savedStateHandle[key, value] map?
first, sorry for my bad eng.
https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app/tree/main
using this app and
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-update-data-room?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-6-pathway-2%3Fhl%3Dko%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-update-data-room#5
reading this chapter
class ItemDetailsViewModel has a statement below.
private val itemId: Int = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle[ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg])
I have known savedStateHandle must have a setting section like
operator fun set(key: String, value: Any?) { initialState[key] = value }
so savedStateHandle loads the value using the key.
At this point, I couldn't find savedStateHandle set his value using ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg key in the app.
Asking ChatGPT, savedStateHandle can't create value automatically, they must directly set the key-value map. But also ChatGPT can't find the setting point.
Am I curious for Being of no use? I can't sleep until I find the answer.
Please somebody put me to sleep.

It is unclear what you are asking. Please [edit] and provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue you have. Put all relevant code directly in the question, links to external sites are not sufficient.

I'm asking before using this code 'savedStateHandle[ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg]', 'savedStateHandle' should have process that key-value is mapped in like this 'savedStateHandle[ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg] = "someValue". and I couldn't find.

That argument is set via Compose Navigation with arguments.
As you can see in InventoryNavGraph.kt, ItemDetailsScreen has one argument in its destination named ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg.
        composable(
            route = ItemDetailsDestination.routeWithArgs,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(ItemDetailsDestination.itemIdArg) {
                type = NavType.IntType
            })
        ) {
            ItemDetailsScreen(
                //...

The argument is set when user navigates from HomeScreen using navigateToItemUpdate
        composable(route = HomeDestination.route) {
            HomeScreen(
                navigateToItemEntry = { navController.navigate(ItemEntryDestination.route) },
                navigateToItemUpdate = {
                    navController.navigate("${ItemDetailsDestination.route}/${it}")
                }
            )
        }


